# SQL export select statement to Excel using script

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel

I have a project that requires me to create a script for migration between test and live data-bases.

What i want to do is create an extract from the test database into an excel sheet or a txt file located in a specified file location.

All in script. 
Is there a query that is able to insert into an excel sheet or a txt file and save it at a specified location?

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567410/i-need-best-practice-in-t-sql-export-data-to-csv-with-header

Answer (score 0):

One general way which requires no EXCEL no OLE DB providers installed on sever machine is to create XML according to MS Office Open XML specification https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-XML-Formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18 .
To create a template for your data just create .xls doc you need using EXCEL 2007+ and save it to XML. Get familiar with format and create a query producing similar XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENROWSET for what you are looking for. Also this may be considered a duplicate, see this question which is asking just about the same thing

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086880/t-sql-export-to-new-excel-file

FYI in order to use this feature, you'll need to have 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' enabled. You can check if its enabled by running

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure
GO
```

'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' will show 0 for config_value if disabled, to enable run this

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE  
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

However by the looks of it this sounds like a school project? In which case you may not be allowed to change these configurations!